# Animating dynamic elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I can't get a fadeout animation working on a dynamically added element.

What I am trying to do is create mechanism where I can have changing backgrounds on a site.

The idea is that I will create a temporary div with the same class as the body, change the class of the body then fade out the temporary div destroying it once the animation is complete.

The linked example is basic. The backgrounds will have different images, not colours in the real thing so using the jQueryUI addClass extension will not work.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamessouth/ScTjq/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. Not sure what you're intending with this animation, but it seems to 'work' this way.

```
    $('#wrapper').fadeOut(2e3, null, function () {
        $page.unwrap($wrap);
    });
```

Comment: I thought that it would work like that I just wasn't happy having to pass the selector twice. I would have thought the way I created the element it would have allowed me to perform any jquery functionality. Is there a better way to create dome elements?